# Keras 2.1.4 + TensorFlow 1.5.0 is 50x slower than K 2.1.3 + TF 1.4.1

Tags: performance, tensorflow, keras

I recently upgraded from Keras 2.1.3 + TensorFlow 1.4.1 to Keras 2.1.4 + TensorFlow 1.5.0. Now it takes 50x longer to train the same model on the same data.

My environment:

```
Arch: x86_64
OS: Debian Stretch
Python: 3.6.4
Packages are managed by conda 4.5.0
TensorFlow is CPU-only
Model is Embedding->LSTM->FC for text classification
```

Same data, same models. Training now takes much longer. For 1 epoch:

```
Keras 2.1.3 + TensorFlow 1.4.1: 4 hours
Keras 2.1.4 + TensorFlow 1.5.0: 200 hours
```

Any hint why?

UPDATE 04/02/2018:

1. Compiled TensorFlow 1.5.1 with CPU optimization and installed it in the conda environment with Keras 2.1.5. Got the same slow performance.
2. Upgraded to TensorFlow 1.6.0 and Keras 1.5.0. Both were anaconda packages for linux-64. Now the performance was even worse, about 100x slower than TF 1.4.1.

Comment: what was the issue ? did you solve it ?

Comment: @DrGeneral, unfortunately no. I have since switched to GPU. You can call it a work-around.